# jQuery on click change when counter start counting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script which count from 60 to 0 and then alert. but i wish to this 60 sec can be changed when i click on box and add 10 more sec or decres 10 sec here is my code on fidle:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/nm3qotsv/2/][1]
```

This code count but when you click on box if time was 40 sec it will add 10 sec and it will be 50 but after 1 sec counter will continueo from 40 not from 50 i wish to continuro from 50

Here is the code:
HTML
    
     Time left 60sec
    
    
    
    
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function minusfif() {
        var number  =   parseInt($('b').html());
        return number - 30;
    }
    function addOne() {
        var number  =   parseInt($('b').html());
        return number + 31;
    }
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $('b').text(minusfif());
    });
    $("#box").click(function(){
        $('b').text(addOne());
    });    
    var counter = parseInt($('#count').html());

        setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
        b = document.getElementById("count");
        b.innerHTML = counter;
        }

        if (counter === 0) {
            alert("aaaa");       
        }

     },1000);   
});
```

CSS:

```
#container{
            border: 1px solid black;
            background: #ff0000;
            width:960px;
            height:500px;

        }
        #box{

            background: black;
            width: 100px;
            height:100px;   
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: Please post your code example in your question. You saw the warning when you linked to jsFiddle without any code in your question.

Comment: Your code is going off the counter variable which is still set on the old counter numbers, when the person clicks the box the counter needs to increase and you need to have that value get put into your counter variable so it knows where to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the concept:

```
var counter = 60;

setInterval(function(){
    counter--;
    ...
    $('b').text(counter); //update counter output every second
}, 1000);

$("#box").click(function(){
    counter += 31;
    $('b').text(counter); //immediately update counter again
});
```